# How do I "shake" an Android device within the Android emulator to bring up the dev menu to debug my React Native app

Tags: android, android-emulator, react-native

I am working on a cross-platform React Native mobile app. I am writing console.log statements as I develop. I want to see these logging statements in Chrome while I'm running the Android app in the default Android emulator. According to [Facebook's docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html) I just need to "shake the device". How do I do this in the Android emulator?

> To access the in-app developer menu:
>
> On iOS shake the device or press control + ⌘ + z in the simulator.
>   On Android shake the device or press hardware menu button (available on older >devices and in most of the emulators, e.g. in genymotion you can press ⌘ + m to >simulate hardware menu button click)

Comment: Also just wanted to add that the docs also say `The Developer Menu is disabled in release (production) builds.` So make sure you are not running a `release` build when you're trying to bring up this menu.

Answer (score 318, accepted):

Within your app in the Android Emulator press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> on macOS or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Sadly F2 no longer works on Linux in Android Emulator 2 beta. What now?

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski I would like to add that, currently in linux, ctrl + m brings up developer menu

Comment: the <kbd>f1</kbd>, ... <kbd>f12</kbd> are confusing and difficult to press in most computers

Comment: I'm probably not going to get any answers on this as this thread is ages old, but I'll say it anyways; This doesn't work for me. Moving the device virtually is not recognized as a shake in my application

Comment: CMD + M just minimises Android Studio for me. How to open the debug menu inside the emulator?

Answer (score 275):

With a React Native running in the emulator,
Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> (for Linux, I suppose it's the same for Windows and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> for Mac OS X)
or run the following in terminal:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

Comment: Not working for me immediately. I needed to go into "settings" ("...") > Settings > Send Keyboard Shorcuts to > Emulator Controls (not virtual device) then it worked.

Comment: ctrl + m doesn't work on linux. This adb shell command works even if i would prefer a shortcut....guess i can make one that launch this command if  i don't find any other way

Comment: To specify a device do `adb -s <device id/serial> shell input keyevent 82`. I use this when using both an emulator and a physical device.

Comment: this answer should marked as the correct answer as its more detailed

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me (using Windows)

Answer (score 83):

If you're using the new emulator that comes with Android Studio 2.0, the keyboard shortcut for the menu key is now Cmd+M, just like in Genymotion.

Alternatively, you can always send a menu button press using `adb` in a terminal:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU
```

Also note that the menu button shortcut isn't a strict requirement, it's just the default behavior provided by the `ReactActivity` Java class (which is used by default if you created your project with `react-native init`). Here's the relevant code from `onKeyUp` in `ReactActivity.java`:

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
  mReactInstanceManager.showDevOptionsDialog();
  return true;
}
```

If you're adding React Native to an existing app ([documentation here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-android.html)) and you aren't using `ReactActivity`, you'll need to hook the menu button up in a similar way. You can also call `ReactInstanceManager.showDevOptionsDialog` through any other mechanism. For example, in an app I'm working on, I added a dev-only Action Bar menu item that brings up the menu, since I find that more convenient than shaking the device when working on a physical device.

Comment: this is not working on MIUI on my mi4i. it just brings up app tray. is there another solution? i really dont want to run it on an emulator as that slows the shit out of my laptop

Comment: it seems there are other issues specific to miui. after enabling notification permission i can now shake device to get the menu. check this thread in case anybody else is having issues with MIUI https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2754

Comment: I edited my post to add more detail on how all this stuff works, which may help you track down the problem. My best guess is you're not using `ReactActivity` and haven't hooked up the menu button through other means.

Comment: thank you for your prompt response :) though the issue was with MIUI permissions manager which did not let the menu dialog show.

Comment: Nice tip about ReactActivity. Seems like that code has now been moved to ReactActivityDelegate.java

Comment: I think I've seen more than 20 SO answers and only this one points where it's handled and I found a fix for my (existing app + react-native) app. Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

For Linux you click on the three dots "..." beside the emulator, on Virtual sensors check "Move" and then try quickly moving either x, y or z coordinates.

[image]

Comment: Actually, thats the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: You can also click the device graphic in the window shown and drag it around.

Comment: Any idea how to do this using adb?

Comment: Only the x direction "shaking" worked for me.

Comment: Did not work for me on Mac OS 12.6 & Android Studio 2022.1.1 Patch 2. No amount of shaking on any axis brought up the react native developer menu.

Answer (score 22):

**'Ctrl + m' works for Windows** in the Android emulator to bring up the React-Native developer menu.

Couldn't find that documented anywhere.
Found my way here, guessed the rest... Good grief.

By the way: OP: You didn't mention what OS you were on.

Answer (score 17):

As while developing react native apps, we play with the terminal so much

so I added a script in the scripts in the **package.json** file

**"menu": "adb shell input keyevent 82"**

and I hit **$ yarn menu**

for the menu to appear on the emulator 
it will forward the keycode 82 to the emulator via ADB
not the optimal way but I like it and felt to share it.

[image]

Comment: Nice workaround!

Comment: Since Emulator settings are unavailable now, this is a solution with the Chipmunk build of AS.

Answer (score 16):

I am on Mac OS so when I press Command, it enable zooming option.
Here is my solution

- Open Configuration window [...] button
- Go to`Settings` tab ->`General` tab -> `Send keyboard shortcuts to` field
- Change value to `Virtual device"` as shown in the picture

After that focus on the emulator and press Command + M, the dev menu appears.

[image: Emulator Option -> Settings -> General]

Comment: I'm not sure how to get to these settings? Is this in Android Studio? On the device? I'm using MacOS. Where do I find this?

Comment: These settings are from the Android Emulator app. Note, this is *very* different from launching an emulator from within Android Studio. If you launch the emulator from within Android Studio, Android Studio wraps the emulator with it's own trash settings that are different from these.

To get what Ponleu has screenshot'd, launch the emulator manually via terminal. Example:`emulator -avd Pixel_5_API_33_2`. You can use `emulator -list-avds` to see what emulators you have configured. 

Docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Answer (score 15):

If you want to simulate a 1 second shake from terminal you can use the following command:

```
adb emu sensor set acceleration 100:100:100; sleep 1; adb emu sensor set acceleration 0:0:0
```

Comment: For Android studio hedgehog, this was the only thing that worked for me. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Works for Android Studio Iguana as well!

Answer (score 11):

'Command + M' for OSX is working for me.

Answer (score 5):

For those for whom `Command + M` simply minimizes the emulator:

1. Exit emulator
2. Go to Setting>Tools>Emulator and uncheck the `Launch in a tool window` checkbox
3. Open emulator
4. now `Command + M` will open developer menu

[image]

Answer (score 4):

on linux ctrl+m should work but it doesn't for solving the problem click on the (...) (its extended controls) and then close that window.now you can open menu by ctrl+m. then:

1. click on the (...) (its extended controls)
2. close extended controls
3. ctrl+m

Comment: For me, this solution almost worked on Linux. I had to press ctrl + m within the extended controls window. Pressing ctrl + m after closing it had no effect.

Answer (score 4):

Use `command + m(cmd + M)` on MAC. Also `make sure that you are accessing your application while you try to access the Debug Menu`i.e. your app must be running otherwise `Cmd + M` will just return the usual ordinary phone menu.

Answer (score 1):

It might be not direct solution, but I've created a lib that allows you to **use 3 fingers touch instead of shake** to open dev menu, when in development mode

https://github.com/pie6k/react-native-dev-menu-on-touch

You only have to wrap your app inside:

import DevMenuOnTouch from 'react-native-dev-menu-on-touch';
// or:  import { DevMenuOnTouch } from 'react-native-dev-menu-on-touch'

```
class YourRootApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DevMenuOnTouch>
        <YourApp />
      </DevMenuOnTouch>
    );
  }
}
```

It's really useful when you have to debug on real device and you have co-workers sitting next to you.

Comment: Yeah, but...shaking it often prepares them for the surprise that is the one day you mistake a cup of chocolate mousse for your cell phone  .'* `~.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying on a *release* build via `adb install -r -d <app-release>.apk`

Make sure you're running the *debug* build, then the menu will work via the shortcut or CLI.