# How to open react-native development menu on VS emulator for android?

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator

I'm trying to use vs emulator for android...

because obviously android studio is terrible,

and I need to keep hyper-v on to use docker for my other projects.

I'd say everything works perfectly,

but the major draw back is I couldn't find the key to open react-native's development menu like in android studio's emulator(ctrl + m).

I tried to search online for one or two hours, but still no luck.

wondering does anyone know how to open it on vs emulator?

or should I just face the truth that it's not gonna work?

Comment: Have you tried triggering the phone shaking in Additional tools/Accelerometer? I don't have a VS emulator at hand so I can't verify.

Comment: yes, there's accelerometer, but the menu doesn't show up like what it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this command

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

For more detail, see [How do I "shake" an Android device within the Android emulator to bring up the dev menu to debug my React Native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914665/how-do-i-shake-an-android-device-within-the-android-emulator-to-bring-up-the-d/37497678#37497678)

Trinita,

Comment: // , Why does this work?

Also, do you have any documentation that we could use to look this up?

Comment: Just as a tip: It would have been useful to include that in your answer.

Comment: it does work!!! OMG tyvm!!! i wish there's a more intuitive way, but i guess it's all better than reboot my computer for disable/enable hyper-v on different projects

Comment: Good ! In VSCode, i 'm try to add this in commande line for an easy access