# React native, debug on simulator or device?

Tags: android, react-native

In the past, the android simulator was painfully slow and I use the device only to debug the android applications.

What's the preferred development environment, simulator, or device for React native application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, emulator can be super fast given the fact that you can configure them as you want (Giving as many RAM as your computer has).

My job is to do mobile app with RN and I almost only user the emulator. For the feature that does not work on it (Opening file with app proposition, for example), I'm using a device.

I also stopped using the debug mode for Android because it is so slow! If you want to look at the `console.log`, you can open a terminal at the root of your project and run `react-native log-android`. It will allow to see the log without being force into debugging

Comment: Thank you for the insightful answer. I'm trying to find out how to shake the device to open up the menu. but my Nexus 5 doesn't seem to recognize `command-M` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914665/how-do-i-shake-an-android-device-within-the-android-emulator-to-bring-up-the-d . Thanks to you, I'll try harder to get it working :)