# Is there a way to enable live reloading and hot reloading in android physical device for react native development?

Tags: android, react-native

I am finding a way of enabling live reloading and hot reloading in android physical device for react native development?

Comment: Hi, you need to shake the phone and it will prompt a menu of different options like enable live reloading, enable hot reloading, debug JS remotely you can enable it from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd . It is working properly.

Comment: Please mark it as a solution so that other people can get help from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For enabling or disabling it you need to shake the phone and it will prompt a menu of different options like enable live reloading, enable hot reloading, debug JS remotely you can enable it from there.

Comment: Also, take a look at the shell commands you can use to trigger that, so that you don't need to break your phone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32914665/how-do-i-shake-an-android-device-within-the-android-emulator-to-bring-up-the-d